# How to add custom buttons to Campaign Influence Related List? (Customizable Campaign Influence)

Tags: related-list, campaign-influence

I've enabled Customizable Campaign Influence and can not add a custom button to Campaign Influence related list. Does anyone now whether it is possible?

Comment: I am running in to the same issue, can you please share your approach on solving this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate a new model attribution on Campaign Influence > Model Settings and uncheck lock field

Comment: If I understand correctly, it should be a custom source model, but I need to use standard one.